# how to import one xml file to another

Tags: android, android-layout

i had an main.xml file and a cell_shape.xml file.

in my main.XML i had this

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:weightSum="100" >

<include
    android:id="tables"
    layout="@layout/cell_shape" />
```

in my cell_shape.XML i had this

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/tables"
    android:shape= "rectangle"  >
        <solid android:color="#000"/>
        <stroke android:width="1dp"  android:color="#ff9"/>
</shape>
```

i had this error

```
Exception raised during rendering: You must specify a valid layout
 reference. The layout ID @layout/cell_shape is not valid. Couldn't
 resolve resource @layout/cell_shape Exception details are logged in
 Window > Show View > Error Log
```

and i don't understand how do i correctly can import if it my main.xml

is there a tutorial on how to import different elements from one xml file to another?

Answer (score 0):

http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2002/07/31/xinclude.html

Maybe this may help you? I had a similar problem and it helped me. If it doesn't... sorry mate... don't have other answers

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `id` in `include`, So it looks just like this:

```
<include
    layout="@layout/cell_shape" />
```

If it does not work, try enclosing the whole cell_shape with one `LinearLayout` or other type of layout.

By the way, for Android design uniformity, please use the color from [this Android site](http://developer.android.com/design/style/color.html).